# WMI: Getting Interface Name,State Network

Tags: c#, networking

Good day.

There are 4 category column in (netsh interface show interface)

1. Admin State (Enabled)
2. State (Disconnected) or (Connected)
3. Type (Dedicated)
4. Interface Name (Ethernet 2) or (Wi-Fi) or (Ethernet)

**Question 1:**
How to get my interface Name where State = "Connected";

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapter");
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
{
    int index = Convert.ToInt32(mo["Index"]);
    string name = mo["NetConnectionID"] as string;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        MessageBox.Show(name);
        //textBox1.Text += name + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

I have here image which i want to be the output.
[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igXCL.png)

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to filter by `NetConnectionStatus == 2`.

**NetConnectionStatus**

- Disconnected (0)
- Connecting (1)
- Connected (2)
- Disconnecting (3)
- Hardware Not Present (4)
- Hardware Disabled (5)
- Hardware Malfunction (6)
- Media Disconnected (7)
- Authenticating (8)
- Authentication Succeeded (9)
- Authentication Failed (10)
- Invalid Address (11)
- Credentials Required (12)

A list of the available Properties and their possible values [can be found in the MSDN entry for Win32_NetworkAdapter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394216(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapter");
mc.GetInstances()
    .OfType<ManagementObject>()
    .Where(mo => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mo["NetConnectionID"] as string)) // has a ConnectionId
    .ToList()
    .ForEach(mo => Debug.WriteLine($"NetConnectionStatus = {mo["NetConnectionStatus"]} / NetConnectionID={mo["NetConnectionID"]} / Name={mo["Name"]}"));

//Result:
//  NetConnectionStatus=7 / NetConnectionID=Ethernet / Name=Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (5) I219-LM
//  NetConnectionStatus=7 / NetConnectionID=WiFi / Name=Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
//  NetConnectionStatus=7 / NetConnectionID=Bluetooth Network Connection / Name=Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)
//  NetConnectionStatus=2 / NetConnectionID=VMware Network Adapter VMnet1 / Name=VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
//  NetConnectionStatus=2 / NetConnectionID=VMware Network Adapter VMnet8 / Name=VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet8
```